# Create a one to many relationship between 2 tables which have composite primary keys

Tags: ms-access

How can I form a many to one relationship between below tables (C2_Code and C3_Code) which both has composite primary keys ?
Or can I ?

[Image of the tables to be linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVcpu.png)

Comment: Compound keys are possible but not recommended. Can have compound index that is not primary key and still use autonumber as PK that is saved in related table as FK. What is this data? Perhaps provide samples in your question as text tables, not images.

Comment: Just drag a line connecting the two code_L1s and another connecting the two code_L2s.  Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access the process to set up a 1 to many relationship between tables with composite keys is drag and drop just like with normal primary keys, but there is a pitfall.  Consider tables 3 & 4 both with composite primary keys.
[image]

Note Table 4 has 2 foreign key columns (A and B) in addition to the composite primary key (C and D).

directions for creating a composite primary key: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/creating-composite-keys-tutorial-for-ms-access

[image]
To create a composite primary key, remove any current primary key then use shift-click to select the fields for your composite key.  The pitfall is you must use primary key in the ribbon rather than right click to set your fields as primary keys.  Both A and B will be marked with the key symbol when you are done.

for the last step go back to the relationships tool shift-click columns A & B in Table 3 and drag them to Table 4 and release.  Then select the usual options and you are done.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I was at holiday so sorry for the late response. Thanks for the answer. The thing I figured wrong was I was trying to link only one part of the compound key not the both (whole). But in fact it was obvious that the key acts as a whole as you indicated. (Btw. I tried to upvote your answer but as I am new, I cannot do that yet.)